# what is the efficient way to use google to search duplicate content..?

Tags: c#

I am making a software that helps to search duplicate contents(only text) in web. I think I can use google as it is very efficient and faster. So I developed an algorithm But it is not efficient.

Here is my idea. The user enters a content of 300-500 character length. This content is searched in google. 1st page results are considered.

ex: Content is "The definition of a breed is a matter of some controversy. Some groups use a definition that ultimately requires extreme in-breeding to qualify. Dogs that are bred in this manner often end up with severe health problems. Other organizations define a breed more loosely, such that an individual may be considered of one breed as long as, say, three of its grandparents were of that breed".

1st result in google : Brief History of Dogs and Breeds. Dog usually means the domestic dog, ... Some groups use a definition that ultimately requires extreme in-breeding to qualify. Dogs that are bred in this manner often end up with severe health problems. Other organizations define a breed more loosely, such that an individual may be ...

So from 1st result we can say the content is present on web ..

My algorithm

```
 bool checkContentVsResult(string googletext, string content)
    {
        bool found = false;
        int len = 0;
        string[] ch = new string[] { "." };
        string[] texts = googletext.Split(ch, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int count = 0,qualify=0;
        len = text.Length;
        if (len > 300)
            qualify = 3;
        else if (len > 200)
            qualify = 2;
        else
            qualify = 1;
        foreach (string s in texts)
        {
            if (s==" ")
                continue;
            if (content.Contains(s))
                count++;
            if (count >= qualify)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

As you can see the algorithm is not much efficient.. How to make it more efficient..?

Comment: so is your plan to check for word similarity? In general content matching/comparison is a much more complex NLP problem, most "easy" solutions won't work very well.

Comment: yeah My plan to check for word similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Try a google search for "levenshtein distance c"?